# Angular Typescript Filter with Dependencies

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-filters

I'm trying to figure out how to write an angular filter in typescript with (and this is the part tripping me up) some injection.

Here is what I have so far:

```
export function StrLimit() {
  return function(input, limit) {
    if (input.length <= limit) {
      return input;
    }
    return $filter('limitTo')(input, limit) + '...';
  }
}

angular.module('myApp').filter('strLimit', StrLimit);
```

I need to get `$filter` injected, and I'd like to use native TS for this.  Any ideas on how to go about doing this?

**Edit: I've seen [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101574/angularjs-filter-with-typescript-and-injection) about this topic, but it seems sloppy to use a module, especially because all of the above is already nested inside a module.**

Comment: What's the problem doing `export function StrLimit($filter) {` and `.filter('strLimit', ['$filter', StrLimit]);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my project we use the `$inject` property like this:

```
export function StrLimit($filter) {
  return function(input, limit) {
    if (input.length <= limit) {
      return input;
    }
    return $filter('limitTo')(input, limit) + '...';
  }
}
StrLimit.$inject = ['$filter'];

angular.module('myApp').filter('strLimit', StrLimit);
```

If you have a typescript class it would be a `public static var $inject = ['$filter'];`

Answer (score 1):

Injecting the $filter property in the registration of the filter got it working for me:

```
export class TableStrictFilter{
    public static Factory($filter:ng.IFilterService) {
        return (input:any, predicate:any) => {
            return $filter('filter')(input, predicate, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Registering the filter:

```
.filter('tableStrictFilter',['$filter', TableStrictFilter.Factory]);
```