# How can we use angular1.x.x filter in typescript?

Tags: angularjs, filter, typescript, angularjs-filter, typescript1.5

I am working on small application using typescript and angularjs. I am trying to inject filter in typescript but i am not able to filter items. I want to search items on enter click. Writing filter in html is not a good idea as a i think. Can anyone please provide sample example or please do the needful.

Thanks,
Sandeep.

Comment: I am using angular 1

Comment: For plain JavaScript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31106002/3029484

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Filter with TypeScript and injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101574/angularjs-filter-with-typescript-and-injection)